# Abnormal Neutral to Earth and Phase to Earth Voltage in Generator

Tags: neutral

We have a 5 KVA Diesel Genset with a 220V AC Output. Also, we have a single phase 220V AC Mains Supply. The genset is connected to a dedicated ground pit with a 10 mm Cable. We have checked the ground pit by connecting Neutral from Mains and Ground Pit with a 0V Reading as well as connected Phase from Mains and Ground pit with 222V Reading.

Now, when we are checking the output from the DG, on Phase to Earth of the DG output socket we are getting 82V to 86V. On Neutral to Earth of the DG output socket we are getting 116V to 117V. And On Phase to Neutral of the DG output socket we are getting 215V.

When we complained to DG team, they said fauly earth. Even we checked with another earth pit having Copper Chemical Earthing but saw same result.

What could be wrong here?

[image]

Comment: The block diagram is missing how the device is wired. Even if you have earthing on the generator frame, it does not mean the earthing connects or generator frame connects to socket PE, and it does not mean that the Neutral connects to PE or generator frame or earthing. So something is missing and we can see that when you provide the wiring.

Answer (score 1):

On some generators, a neutral-to-ground link is an optional fitting.

Without it, the frame of the generator is grounded, but the generator itself is floating.  So the neutral-to-ground and phase-to-ground voltages can vary wildly.

With the link fitted, the neutral-to-ground voltage should be very low, and the phase-to-ground should be 220V.